# custom legend in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, legend

I am trying to set a legend here, and so far got one with incorrect colors, pls help me amend this.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.set(style='whitegrid')

ax=sns.pointplot(data=june_avg, x='Hour', y='bike_count', color='black')
ax=sns.pointplot(data=houravg, x='Hour', y='bike_count', color='green')

plt.legend(title='Avg Bike Rent', loc='upper left', labels=['Annaul', 'June'])
ax.set(xlabel='Hour', ylabel='Bike Count')
plt.title('Annual Avg vs June Avg Rent per Hour', fontsize=17, pad=30)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767489/add-legend-to-seaborn-point-plot

Comment: @ FlyingTeller thanks, used the solution with mpatches and worked perfectly, very easy to implement

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to change the legend afterwards, which [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767489/add-legend-to-seaborn-point-plot) also has no solution for, I would suggest to combine your two dataframes in a way so that you can have a single `pointplot` call with a `hue` variable:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

#Create some dummy data
june_avg = pd.DataFrame({'Hour': range(24), "bike_count": np.random.randint(800,1000,size=(24,))})
houravg = pd.DataFrame({'Hour': range(24), "bike_count": np.random.randint(400,600,size=(24,))})

#Introduce Extra column that we use for the hue keyword. Content is what we want in the legend
june_avg["Avg Bike Rent"] = "June"
houravg["Avg Bike Rent"] = "Annual"

#Settings from your question
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.set(style='whitegrid')

#Single plot command
sns.pointplot(data=pd.concat([june_avg,houravg ]), x="Hour", y="bike_count", hue="Avg Bike Rent", ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]